# How to make a continuous Cell in NSOutlineView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I want to have a continuous Cell, which is not cropped to the width of the corresponding table column. Returning `YES` to the `- (BOOL)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView isGroupItem:(id)item` delegate method takes no effect.

This screenshot visualizes my problem:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is this an `NSTableView` or an `NSOutlineView`?  If it's an `NSOutlineView`, is your delegate being called?

Comment: Sorry of course it is an NSOutlineview. The delegate is being called, but the cell gets Not continous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), `outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:item:` will be called a first time with the table column parameter set to `nil`. If you return a cell in that case (as opposed to returning `nil`), it will be used to draw group rows.